# IFS variable ignored in system()

Tags: shell, environment-variables, c

For a class at my university I am trying to achieve a privilege escalation. I have this simple code that simply replicates the output of `ls` and has `SUID` bit set.

```
int main(void){
  system("/bin/ls");
  return 0;
}
```

And I have added the script that is going to serve as shell in the home directory as well:

```
#!/bin/bash
/bin/sh
```

And I have added `.` in the `$PATH` variable as well, and it is the first one. So what should happen is that whenever I run the code in C, that should call the `bin` script in the home directory, however the `IFS` variable is completely ignored, because it runs indeed the `/bin/ls` and not `bin ls`. Any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

Your program does not execute a "**`bin`** script in the home directory".  It executes `"/bin/ls"`.  The system call uses the shell, but also using an absolute pathname (actually [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/system.html) says the way it is executed is implementation defined). There is no way that `PATH` would affect either the choice of `ls` or the shell.

[POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_03) addresses the behavior of `IFS`, saying:

> Implementations may ignore the value of **`IFS`** in the environment, or the absence of **`IFS`** from the environment, at the time the shell is invoked, in which case the shell shall set **IFS** to `<space>` `<tab>` `<newline>` when it is invoked.

If you were asking about an implementation which does *not* behave this way, then (because POSIX implies that this is done often enough to note) the particular implementation would be pertinent.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the shell invoked by `system` to execute the command `/bin/ls` were to respect the value of `IFS` in the environment, it would have no effect on the parsing of that command line:

1. `IFS` is not used to parse shell commands. The command is split into words using the shell grammar, which precisely specifies how the line is to be tokenized. (Metacharacters terminate tokens; some metacharacters also are tokens.)
2. Word-splitting, which does respect `IFS`, is only performed on unquoted input *which undergoes some form of substitution.* So if the command were `$cmd` and the value of the variable `cmd` were `/bin/ls`, then `IFS` would be used to word-split the substituted text. But:
3. Word-splitting `/bin/ls` with `/` in `IFS` results in *three* words. the first of which is empty. The empty word cannot be used as a command, so that will throw some sort of error, rather than attempting to execute `bin`.

Comment: any ideas on how to invoke the command to achieve similar results then?